# Web Based file manager (I'm on a hosting account)

Tags: php

I seem to be having issues accessing my cpanel from work and so I'm trying to find a web-based file editor that can serve as an alternative. However, all of those that I found require me to have actual linux server access.

I'm just looking for a simple php editor that I can set up and use to edit and manage a couple of files.

Thanks!

Comment: and which ones did you find, or what access did you need?

Comment: [php file manager](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Hi Nanne, I tried eXtplorer, ecoder & Brackets

Comment: However as I soon found out, you need to be able to do this to run them `git clone https://github.com/adobe/brackets-app.git
cd brackets-app`

Comment: na, you don't. That's just a way to get the files on your server. You can do that somewhere else (or just download them) and then upload them trough whatever access means you have (ftp? desk)

Comment: Really? Well, I have complete hosting cpanel/ftp access, however from reading the installaction docs on things such as ecoder, where the root drive started with C:\, that's when I became cautious.

Comment: A pooly written file manager just creates another door an attacker could nibble at. You would be better of using ssh to tunnel your connection to your server if its a NAT issue. Or even just use FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't install a Web based file manager on your hosting account, you can use online tools.

https://codeanywhere.net/ is really nice.

Or You can check this list to find the more appropriate file editor you need.
http://www.smashingapps.com/2010/12/07/11-robust-web-based-editors-to-code-directly-from-your-browser.html

Comment: Thanks timmalos, codeanywhere seems really nice. Too bad they have a 60mb restriction.